# match everything after a slash and without the slash

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am working with regular expression with the module re in python. I am supose to match everything before a slash, put the match in a variable, and match everything after a slash, and put it in another variable.

For example:

for the string

```
"NlaIII/Csp6I"
```

I would like to match NlaIII and store it in a variable and match Csp6I and store it in another variable

```
variable_1 = "NlaIII"
variable_2 = "Csp6I"
```

Using python module re, I have been able to match everything before the slash with the following regular expression:

```
first_enzyme = re.compile('.+?(?=\W+)')
```

But I am completely unable to  **everything after a backslash without the backslash**

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Split with `/`, it the simplest solution for this kind of strings.

Comment: / is a slash, \ is a backslash. Which one do you want?

Comment: `variable_1, variable_2  = "NlaIII/Csp6I".split("/")`

Comment: sorry, I have mix between a slash and a backslash, when I mean backslash, it is a slash. I edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex for that at all.

```
s = "NlaIII/Csp6I"
variable_1, variable_2 = s.split('/')
```